# How to have an Immutable.js optional (TypeScript) Record class property

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

If you attempt to have a `Record` class with an optional property, like so:

```
class MyRecord extends Immutable.Record({
  field: undefined
}) {
  field?: string;
}
```

...you get a TypeScript error like so:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] myFile.ts:x:y
TS2415: Class 'MyRecord' incorrectly extends base class 'Instance<{ field: undefined; }> & Readonly<{ field: undefined; }>'.
  Type 'MyRecord' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ field: undefined; }>'.
  Types of property 'field' are incompatible.
  Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

If you get rid of the `field` default value like so:

```
class MyRecord extends Immutable.Record({}) {
  field?: string;
}
```

...Typescript doesn't complain any more, but then you are unable to set the field property on class instances (because of the `Record` API).

How are we supposed to get around this, if we want an optional property?

---

Typescript version:   2.2.1

Immutable.js version: 4.0.0-rc-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript does not look at the subclass body when inferring the type of the superclass.

The type the superclass is inferred from `Immutable.Record({ field: undefined })` to be `Immutable.Record<{ field: undefined }>`. Therefore, the subclass’ type is incompatible with the superclass.

To fix this, you have to declare the type information at the superclass, not the subclass:

```
class MyRecord extends Immutable.Record<{
  field?: string
}>({
  field: undefined
}) { }
```